# PreventUserIdleSystemSleep Process on a MacBook Pro

Tags: macos, sleep, macbook, macbook-pro, power-management

My girlfriend's Macbook Pro appears to no longer go to sleep when closing the lid, so that the battery depletes really fast. As I'm no Mac expert, I looked around, and learned to look at the processes from a terminal window. Here's what I get:

```
$ pmset -g assertions
2019-11-18 17:09:28 +0100 
Assertion status system-wide:
   BackgroundTask                 0
   ApplePushServiceTask           0
   UserIsActive                   1
   PreventUserIdleDisplaySleep    0
   PreventSystemSleep             0
   ExternalMedia                  0
   PreventUserIdleSystemSleep     1
   NetworkClientActive            0
Listed by owning process:
   pid 98(apsd): [0x00017c2a000b9fbe] 00:00:01 ApplePushServiceTask named: "com.apple.apsd-lastpowerassertionlinger" 
   pid 71490(fud): [0x00017c2800019fbb] 00:00:02 PreventUserIdleSystemSleep named: "com.apple.MobileAccessoryUpdater.SleepAssertionID.ModalClient" 
   pid 121(hidd): [0x000179b900099f0e] 00:00:00 UserIsActive named: "com.apple.iohideventsystem.queue.tickle.4294975120.3" 
    Timeout will fire in 120 secs Action=TimeoutActionRelease
   pid 2501(cloudphotosd): [0x00017b72000b9f74] 00:22:11 BackgroundTask named: "com.apple.cloudphotosd.darkwake.sync" 
    Details: cloudphotosd darkwake power assertion for initial and large iCPL downloads/uploads
    Timeout will fire in 468 secs Action=TimeoutActionTurnOff
No kernel assertions.
Idle sleep preventers: IODisplayWrangler
```

So, `pid 71490(fud): [0x00017c2800019fbb] 00:00:02 PreventUserIdleSystemSleep named: "com.apple.MobileAccessoryUpdater.SleepAssertionID.ModalClient"` seems to be the culprit, but I don't know what to do with it. Any guidance would be welcome.

Comment: See https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/309329/what-is-mobileaccessoryupdater-and-why-it-runs-on-my-macbook

Comment: You can get an overview of what's preventing sleep in Activity Monitor. From Veiw menu, select "All Processes" then in the CPU tab, right click any header & check Preventing Sleep. Sort on that column to see what is responsible.

Comment: @Tetsujin: yes, but that's what's preventing sleep while you're using the computer.  Isn't the only thing that matters what is preventing sleep when you close the lid?

Comment: @iconoclast - it's a fairly simple elimination process. hidd will get out of your way, as it only 'prevents sleep' until the machine is asked to sleep [idk why it does that, but it does]. Anything else ought to be fairly obvious - eg https://i.stack.imgur.com/O6FOC.png

Comment: yes but you still have to manually monitor and detect that something is preventing sleep, and you have to be eternally vigilant about it.

Comment: @iconoclast - that wasn't a criterion of the question, nor was my comment an answer.